# Download image from image tag with background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas, base64

Hi I am having proble while downloading the image from image tag, I have googled it but not getting any valid solutions. Can anyone help to get solve this..
Actually I am binding some bytestring to the image tag src like this

```
<img src="' + this.el.toDataURL("image/png") +'" class="img-responsive imgSmall" style="background-color:green;" alt="img" data-position-to="origin" data-transition="slide" id="signPrevwID_' + signatureid +'">
```

and I am downloading the the same image with background color green but its not working,everytime its saving with background color black only, for downloading Im using this code

```
 var bannerImage = document.getElementById('signPrevwID_' + signatureid );
var imgData = getBase64Image(bannerImage);
console.log("imgData - "+imgData);
//alert("imgData - "+imgData);

 var newName = 'Test_' + new Date().getTime()+".png";

var fileWritter = new AppUtils.FileWritter(newName);
fileWritter.saveBase64ToBinary(imgData, function(r){
    console.log("saveBase64ToBinary() file saved");
  }, function(e){  
     console.log("saveBase64ToBinary() file not saved");
  });

var AppUtils2 = (function(){

//alert("AppUtils2");
// get the application directory. in this case only checking for Android and iOS
function localFilePath(filename) {
    if(device.platform.toLowerCase() === 'android') {
        return cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;
    } else if(device.platform.toLowerCase() == 'ios') {
        return cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;
    }
}

// FileWritter class
function FileWritter(filename) {
    //deleteStoredFromDevice(filename);
    this.fileName = filename;
    this.filePath = localFilePath(filename);

    alert("fileName - "+fileName);
}

// decode base64 encoded data and save it to file
FileWritter.prototype.saveBase64ToBinary = function(data, ok, fail) {
    var byteData = atob(data);

    var byteArray = new Array(byteData.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = byteData.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var binaryData = (new Uint8Array(byteArray)).buffer;


   // createDirectory();
    this.saveFile(binaryData, ok, fail);
}

// save file to storage using cordova
FileWritter.prototype.saveFile = function(data, ok, fail) {
    this.fileData = data;

    var path = this.filePath.substring(0, this.filePath.lastIndexOf('/'));

    //console.log("saveFile() path - "+path);
    var that = this;

    // Write file on local system
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+"Download/Mobitrac/Docs", function(directoryEntry) {
        var options = {create: true, exclusive: false};

        alert("that.fileName - "+cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+"Download/Mobitrac/Docs");

        directoryEntry.getFile(that.fileName, options, function(file) {

            alert("that.fileName - "+that.fileName);

            file.createWriter(function(writer) {
                writer.onwriteend = function(event) {
                    if(typeof ok === 'function') {
                        alert("onwriteend");
                        //viewing documents locally
                        //var fileWritter = new AppUtils.viewFile(subEventId+'.'+fileExtention);
                        ok(event);
                    }
                };

                writer.write(that.fileData);
            }, fail);
        }, fail);

    }, fail);
};  

/*// open InApp Browser to view file
function viewFile(filename) {
    //var path = localFilePath(filename);
    var path = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+"Download/Mobitrac/Docs/"+filename;
    alert("viewFile() path - - "+path);
    window.open(path, "_system", "location=yes,hidden=no,closebuttoncaption=Close");
}

return {
    FileWritter: FileWritter,
    localFilePath: localFilePath,
    viewFile: viewFile
}*/
 })();
   var fileExtention = '';


function getBase64Image(img) {
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

console.log("data - "+dataURL);

  return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png);base64,/, "");
}
```

Byte string im getting with sketch.js canvas element, I mean Im drawing something on canvas and appening same image to the img tag in html with background color green.

I am not getting from where its breaking, please anybody help me

Comment: black or transparent ? `drawImage` will only draw the content of your image i.e the media loaded. All your css will be ignored. If you want to add a background first, you'll have to call `fillRect()` after you set the correct `fillStyle` on the entire area of your canvas before drawing the image.

Comment: black color only, not transparant.. I will try with fillrect and fillstyle now

Comment: @Kaiido Fillrect and fillstyle is workinf fine.. But image width and height is not working.. I mean image tag size should come and sit in canvas right

Comment: not if you modified the tag's `width` and `height` attributes. In this case, you'll need to get the image's `.naturalWidth` and `.naturalHeight` properties instead.

Comment: @Kaiido, canvas width is storing, so I have place filerect with canvas width, its working fine..